# Move one slider around another. JqueryUi

Tags: jquery-ui, slider

How to make one slider control another using jquery ui? I tried to follow [this tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/282944/jquery-one-slider-controls-another), but 'moveTo' action seems to be too old and doesn't work nowadays. I tested the function below and it doesn't seem to work, it keeps repeating one last function.

```
<div id="slider-1" class="slider-range" onclick="move()"></div>

<div id="slider-2" class="slider-range"></div>


function moveSlider2(e, ui) {
    jQuery('#slider-2').slider('value', ui.value);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`moveTo` was deprecated indeed, but you can still use `value` method to do essentially the same thing: set a value for a slider programmatically. Note that if you work with sliders, you should work with sliders - and listen to the events raised by this library. For example:

```js
const sliders = ['#slider-1', '#slider-2', '#slider-3'].map(
  selector => $(selector).slider({
    min: 1,
    max: 5,
    step: 0.1
  })
);
sliders.forEach($el => {
  // listening to `slide` event, fired when value is changed by a user
  $el.on('slide', (_, {value}) => {
    sliders.forEach($slider => $slider.slider('value', value));
  });
});
```

```css
.slider-range {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 5%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/cupertino/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<div id="slider-1" class="slider-range"></div>
<div id="slider-2" class="slider-range"></div>
<div id="slider-3" class="slider-range"></div>
```